# Breadcrumbs Issue with React Router (6.16.0) and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been working on learning React-Router (6.16.0) by creating a simple `Breadcrumbs` navigation using `isMatches()` as they recommend in their documentation here: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-matches.

Using their documentation I set up the below `createBrowserRouter` and `Breadcrumbs` component. For the life of me I can't get display the breadcrumbs. Instead I get the following error: `Type 'IMatches' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)` and I can't access anything in the crumb and display it using `.map`

Everything I've read about TypeScript tells me that the `handle` being returned in the `isMatches()` as type "unknown" or the type of the `crumb` is the likely cause of my issues. I've tried to set `handle` to be a string in the interface IMatches, an Array, etc.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on this?

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, BrowserRouter, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import ErrorPage from './components/404/error-page';
import Profile from './components/profile/profilepage';
import Root from './root';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    handle: [
      {
        crumb: <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
      }
    ],
    children: [
      {
        path: "profile/:userId",
        element: <Profile />,
        handle: [
          {
            crumb: <Link to="profile/:userId">Profile</Link>
          }
        ]
      },
    ],
    
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <RouterProvider router={router} />
   
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

src/components/breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.tsx

```
import { match } from "assert";
import { stringify } from "querystring";
import { Params, useMatches } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Breadcrumbs() {

  interface IMatches {
    id: string;
    pathname: string;
    params: Params<string>;
    data: unknown;
    handle: unknown;     
  } 
    
  //the matches
  const initialMatches: IMatches[] = useMatches()

  console.log(initialMatches);

  const crumbs = initialMatches
    .filter((match) => Boolean(match.handle)) 

    
  return (
    <ol>
      {crumbs.map((crumb, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{crumb}</li>
      ))} 
    </ol>
  );
}
```

`Console.log(initialMatches)` gives out this object in DevTools

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "pathname": "/",
        "params": {
            "userId": "2"
        },
        "handle": [
            {
                "crumb": {
                    "type": {},
                    "key": null,
                    "ref": null,
                    "props": {
                        "to": "/",
                        "children": "Dashboard"
                    },
                    "_owner": null,
                    "_store": {}
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0-0",
        "pathname": "/profile/2",
        "params": {
            "userId": "2"
        },
        "handle": [
            {
                "crumb": {
                    "type": {},
                    "key": null,
                    "ref": null,
                    "props": {
                        "to": "profile/:userId",
                        "children": "Profile"
                    },
                    "_owner": null,
                    "_store": {}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried to do some of the following:

1. Set `handle` in my interface to an `Array`, `string[]` and `any`
2. I've tried to create a separate interface for `handle` and set `initialMatches.handle` to it's own Array and iterate through that

I expected to be able to at least `console.log(initialMatches.handle[0])` after setting the interface to equal the Array that isMatches() returns but when I do that I get an error in VS as `"Property 'handle' does not exist on type 'IMatches[]'`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Drew Resse' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77115282/21013024)
To fix the typescript error on matches, I created the following types

```
import { Params } from "react-router-dom";

interface IMatches {
  id: string;
  pathname: string;
  params: Params<string>;
  data: unknown;
  handle: unknown;
}

type HandleType={
 crumb : (param?: string) => React.ReactNode;
}

const matches: IMatches[] = useMatches();
const crumbs = matches
.filter((match) =>
  Boolean(match.handle && (match.handle as 
  HandleType).crumb)
)
.map((match) => {
  const crumb = (match.handle as HandleType).crumb(
    match.data as string | undefined
  );
  return crumb as React.ReactNode;
});
```

This helped get rid of the type error. You can map through crumb and it should display the breadcrumb.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Breadcrumbs` component the `crumbs` variable is still an array of `IMatches`.

```js
const initialMatches: IMatches[] = useMatches()

const crumbs = initialMatches
  .filter((match) => Boolean(match.handle)); // <-- still an IMatches[]
```

You've only filtered the `initialMatches` array.

In the docs you linked to you can see they take an extra step of also mapping the filtered matches to an array of crumbs

> ```
> let matches = useMatches();
> let crumbs = matches
>   // first get rid of any matches that don't have handle and crumb
>   .filter((match) => Boolean(match.handle?.crumb))
>   // now map them into an array of elements, passing the loader
>   // data to each one
>   .map((match) => match.handle.crumb(match.data));
> ```

Here's a simple update to your code to get the breadcrumbs working with the given data/routes. Notice that the `handle` is an object (*not array!*) with a `crumb` property that is a function that takes a string parameter and returns a `ReactNode` (*e.g. JSX*).

```
interface IMatches {
  id: string;
  pathname: string;
  params: Params<string>;
  data: unknown;
  handle: {
    crumb: (param?: string) => React.ReactNode;
  };
}

function Breadcrumbs() {
  // The matches
  const initialMatches: IMatches[] = useMatches();

  const crumbs = initialMatches
    .filter((match) => Boolean(match.handle?.crumb))
    .map((match) => match.handle.crumb(match.params.userId));

  return (
    <ol>
      {crumbs.map((crumb, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{crumb}</li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
}
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    handle: {
      crumb: () => <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: "profile/:userId",
        element: <Profile />,
        handle: {
          crumb: (userId: string) => (
            <Link to={`/profile/${userId}`}>Profile {userId}</Link>
          )
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

[image: Edit breadcrumbs-issue-with-react-router-6-16-0-and-typescript]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help on this! Your response certainly helped me see where I was making the errors and thank you for the codesandbox! I'm currently stuck on the `const initialMatches: IMatches[] = useMatches();` line. For some reason my code doesn't want to accept that and is saying that initialMatches is not assignable to IMatches[]. All the other errors cleared up!

I'm going to play around with it some more this weekend as I see it's working in your CodeSandbox. Any idea why it's not working in VS?

Comment: @user3670371 Might just be a Typescript versioning issue.

Comment: @user3670371 Did this answer help address/resolve your posted question/issue?